# How to erase SQLite database on restart of app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I developed a SQLite database for my android application, which I want to debug. I create the table as here:

```
String CREATE_ROUTES_TABLE = 
       "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + DATABASE_INTERNAL_NAME + " ( " +
        PRIMARY_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        ROUTE_ID + " TEXT," +
        AGENCY_ID + " TEXT," +
        ROUTE_SHORT_NAME + " TEXT," +
        ROUTE_LONG_NAME + " TEXT," +
        ROUTE_TYPE + " INTEGER );";
```

But here, when it was once created, on each restart the table is filled again with same values. I would like to empty and refill the table on each restart. Removing the "IF NOT EXISTS" in front of the "CREATE TABLE" statement did not help.

**How can I start with a new database on each time restarting the app?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try on this way its work fine like.
this is mention at  `onUpgrade()` in your comman SQL Class.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ORDER);

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TIMESTAMP);

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ACCOUNT);

    // hardik
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_IMAGE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_UPDATEITEMS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SCANITEMS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use DatabaseAdapters. In my case it is handeld via `public class MySpecialDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper` with the two overriden methods onCreate() and onUpgrade()